# Must chewing gum be removed before saying a bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, bal-tashchit-waste

Given that [it's preferable to have an empty mouth when saying a bracha](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.50b?lang=he) must I remove chewing gum from my mouth before saying a bracha - for example, for a glass of water, or anything else for that matter - and if so does it make a difference if taking it out would mean I wouldn't want to continue chewing it after (which would result in wasting food)?

Comment: I wonder: Is gum even considered food? It isn't supposed to be swallowed...

Comment: Many people do swallow it though. I often do if I'm not near a rubbish bin.

Comment: I suppose this question is a duplicate of the second question in your link. I note that a response on that question noted that the two questions are distinct and should be separated and I guess I've unintentionally done that!

Comment: True, but I still wonder if it is considered food. It is just a piece of rubber, maybe with some sugar mixed in. Swallowing rubber doesn't make rubber food.

Comment: Whether or not it's food, there's still an issue with having it in the mouth when saying a bracha?

Comment: In U.S. society, and I assume most of the world, talking while eating or chewing is disrespectful. In school, my teachers would sometimes make us wear the gum on our nose if s/he caught us chewing gum, because it was disrespectful to the teacher. One should act respectfully when praying to God. So, in my opinion (I have no halachic backup, now. Worth my research on this), I would consider chewing gum, or anything at all a matter of disrespect to God while talking to Him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orach Chaim 172:2 - you should remove the candy from your mouth and make a Bracha. If it is chewed and unappetizing to remove, you may push it to the side of your mouth and make a Bracha.

Answer (score 3):

Your mouth should be empty when saying a bracha:
We learn this from the passuk:  (Tehillim 71:8) 
 Let my mouth be filled with Your praise ימלא פי תהילתך
The emphasis is on our mouths not having something else inside, so that they are only filled with G-d's praise and nothing else - it would seem to me irrelevant whether it was food or something else.

(I can't find the source for this, but if I remember correctly, it is in connection with someone who forgot to make a bracha and that he needs to take the food out of his mouth before making the bracha.)